# Using Django ModelForm for one-to-many relationships

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, one-to-many, modelform

I'm trying to extend the Django (version 2.0) tutorial so that it uses ModelForm to create a question with a least one or two choices. I have two models Question and Choice which have a one-to-many relationship. What do I need to do to my model, form, views, and template to generate a field(s) for choice? I've seen a few posts suggesting [Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) but that seems like it's only for admin pages.

**polls/models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**polls/forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Choice, Question


class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_text', 'pub_date', 'choice']
```

**polls/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
from .forms import QuestionForm
from .models import Choice, Question



def create_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question_text = form.cleaned_data['question_text']
            pub_date = form.cleaned_data['pub_date']
            question = Question(question_text=question_text, pub_date=pub_date)
            question.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:index'))
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/create-question.html', {'form': form})
```

**polls/create-question.html**

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% block scripts %}{% endblock scripts %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Create question</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'polls:create-question' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ModelForm you should add a ManyToManyField to the Question model in order to connect choices with the certain question. For example like `choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.